# How To Turning A MultiIndex Dataframe into a Singular Index Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the current code that is used to read a file and then remove 1 line from the top of the dataframe until a specific value is 'ACCIDENT ID'.

```
def read_file(file):
    """
    This function reads the Excel file, chooses the sheet that contains the information that we need.
    The sheet is then read and the dataframe is created.
    """
    
    df = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    
    # Setting string to obtain correct sheet name.
    sheet_prefix = 'ITD_'

    # Go through each sheet and obtain the one with ITD_.
    for sheet_name in df.sheet_names:
        if sheet_prefix in sheet_name:
            read_sheet = sheet_name
        else:
            invalid_sheet_name = True

    df_read = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=str(read_sheet))
        
    df_duplicate = df_read.copy()
    
    # Check if the first cell contains ACCIDENT ID.
    while df_duplicate.columns.values[0][0] != 'ACCIDENT ID':
    
        columns_list = [df_duplicate.iloc[0].values]
        df_duplicate.columns = columns_list
        df_duplicate = df_duplicate.iloc[1:]
    
    df_before = df_duplicate
    df_duplicate = df_duplicate.dropna(how='all', axis='columns')
    df_duplicate = df_duplicate.reset_index(drop=True)
    
    return df_duplicate
```

What I don't understand is that when I read the file into excel, the dataframe is a single index. However at the end of the function the dataframe that is returned is now multiindex? I thought reset_index would turn the dataframe back into a singular index. This ends up messing up my functions later as the columns are in a different form. Does anyone know how to turn the dataframe back so the column headers are of a singular index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the issues that I was having was because I was assigning the value in the rows to the columns and that meant that a multi index dataframe was being created. In order to fix this, I needed to make sure that the values were being flattened and then being turned into a list. The following code fixes this issue.

```
column_regex = df_duplicate.columns.values.flatten().tolist()
```

Then assigning this list to the column headers fixed my issue and maintained the dataframe as a singular index dataframe.